Improve readability of navbar menu
I designed a simple responsive menu using Bootstrap 5:

I don't like it very much because it seems there is no clear separation among the items. Putting it in another way, looking at the middle, it's not clear whether an icon is associated to the word on the left or on the right.
How can I improve it? Should I insert a separator (like a vertical rule) or increase the spacing between the items or anything else?

Consider an alternative: Is there a particular reason you need icons?
You're right in identifying the problem of which label the icons might apply to, but consider an alternative: A more standard horizontal navbar that only uses text labels.
Here's Jakob's law

Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know.

Icons and labels are standard in side navigation, not horizontal navigation bars.
With side navigation, it's much easier to discern the icon and label relationship, and users can vertically scan the list with ease. This allows users to even ignore the icons, looking only at the text labels if they prefer.

Good point. Actually, I changed the menu from side bar to top navbar, without asking myself if the icons should be left there or not.

I'd like to add that icons (for navigation) only make sense if they appear on their own, without the text, somewhere on the UI. One example may be left-side navigation panel which can be collapsed to only show icons. If there is no place where icons appear by themselves, I'd get rid of them.

I see two big problems:

Relationship of icons to each other
Relationship of icons/text

I don't know where you got the icons from, but I must tell you that they lack a very elaborate design.
Almost all the icons have a different height, in some cases it is a 25% difference:

I would recommend first of all studying the icon's design if they are customized or using icons with standard designs like Fontawesome's, which, if you look closely, have a proportional width/height ratio.

Design based on a 16x16 grid:

Read more about Fontawesome Icons Design Consistency
Secondly, the relationship between icon and text. As is the current design, the icons are oversized, reaching double the height of the text.

I would try to find an optically proportional and equitable relationship, for example by looking for some reference parameter. In the example, the height of the icon goes from the descender line of the font to above the ascender line, an increment equal to the difference between the ascender and the x-height:



The icons are from the official Bootstrap's set: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

Perhaps Bootstrap's priority is something other than optimizing the design of its icon library. At first glance, they have a rather sloppy design.
